# onRecevie method not invoked in BroadcastRecevier

Tags: android

Here,in the OutgoingReceiver its inner onReceive method is not invoking when the  class is called. 
       but when i am calling OutgoingReciver class it is only calling its constructor. not able to call method inside it.

Can connection is established of outgoing call.

How to invoke the class myListener so that it can tell that call is in which state like onCalling, onCallEstablished.

Its manifest file is:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/> 

     <receiver android:name=".OutgoingReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

class OutgoingRecevier:-

```
        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.sip.SipAudioCall;
        import android.util.Log;

       public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
       {
        public OutgoingReceiver() 
        {   
           Log.d("outgoing","in outgoing listener");

           //this is been called
        }

     // but not invoking this onRecevie method. Were i am wrong??

      @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
       { 
     Log.d("onRecevice","hi");

     String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

     SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new myListener(context);

   }
 }
```

myListener class:-

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.sip.SipAudioCall;
    import android.net.sip.SipException;
    import android.net.sip.SipProfile;
    import android.util.Log;

    class myListener extends SipAudioCall.Listener {
private Context context;

public myListener(Context context)
{
    Log.d("mylistener","i am in");
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
    try {
        Log.d("inRinging","in");
        call.answerCall(30);
    } catch (SipException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onReadyToCall(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.d("ReadyCall","IncomingCallReceiver.java onReadyToCall : " + call.toString());
}

@Override
public void onCalling(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.d("Calling","IncomingCallReceiver.java onCalling : " + call.toString());
}

@Override
public void onRingingBack(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.d("RingingBack","IncomingCallReceiver.java onRingingBack : " + call.toString());
}

@Override
public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.d("CallEstablished","IncomingCallReceiver.java onCallEstablished : " + call.toString());
    if (call.isInCall()) {
        Log.d("CallEstablished","IncomingCallReceiver.java isInCall : " + call.toString());

    }
    if (call.isOnHold()) { 
        Log.d("CallEstablished","IncomingCallReceiver.java isOnHold : " + call.toString());
    }
    if (call.isMuted()) {
        Log.d("CallEstablished","IncomingCallReceiver.java isMuted : " + call.toString());
    }

    call.startAudio();
}

@Override
public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.d("CallEnded","IncomingCallReceiver.java onCallEnded : " + call.toString());
}

@Override
public void onCallBusy(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.d("CallBusy","IncomingCallReceiver.java onCallBusy : " + call.toString());
}

@Override
public void onCallHeld(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.d("CallHeld","IncomingCallReceiver.java onCallHeld : " + call.toString());
}

@Override
public void onError(SipAudioCall call, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
    Log.d("CallError","IncomingCallReceiver.java IncomingCallReceiver.java onError : " + call.toString() + "; errorCode: " + errorCode + "; errorMessage: " + errorMessage);
}

@Override
public void onChanged(SipAudioCall call) {
    Log.d("CallChanged","IncomingCallReceiver.java onReadyToCall : " + call.toString());
}
```

}

Mainactivity :-

```
           .
           .   //code
           .

          if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) 

           {

           Log.i("endcallListener hook", "OFFHOOK");

          IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL);

         //called here

            BroadcastReceiver br = new OutgoingReceiver();

            getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(br,intentFilter);

        }
       .
       .   //code
       .
```

output:-

```
       I/endcallListener hook: OFFHOOK
       D/outgoing: in outgoing listener
       //terminated
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture an outgoing call by using TelephonyManager then do this:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);   
tm.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch(state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if(incomingNumber==null) {
                    //outgoing call
                } else {
                    //incoming call
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                if(incomingNumber==null) {
                    //outgoing call
                } else {
                    //incoming call
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};
```